# What is the proper way to delay a service worker update check?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'd like to only have the service worker update check occur eg 5 mins into the app being used.

Problem is that because it's wrapped in

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceWorker.js");      
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
```

it starts its checks at load time.

To get around it I put the service worker init in a function that I can call whenever I want, but of course, it fails because...

```
window.addEventListener('load', async ()
```

was called after the window was loaded.

What's the general idea for delaying service worker checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider `await`ing [`ServiceWorkerContainer.register()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register).

The following `registerSingletonServiceWorkerUrls` implementation demonstrates how to register service worker URLs and retrieve the resulting [`ServiceWorkerRegistration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration) as needed using [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.

````
/**
 * Registers the given service worker
 * URLs (if not already registered).
 *
 * @returns The resulting value of the current client's
 * `ServiceWorkerContainer`'s `ServiceWorkerRegistration`.
 * 
 * Example use:
 * ```
 * const latestServiceWorkerRegistration = await registerSingletonServiceWorkerUrls(
 *     '/service_worker_1.js',
 *     '/service_worker_2.js',
 * )
 * ```
 */
function registerSingletonServiceWorkerUrls(
    ...serviceWorkerUrls
) {
  return new Promise(
      async resolve => {
        // Wait for the document to finish loading (if applicable):
        while (document.readyState !== 'complete') await tick()

        for (const url of serviceWorkerUrls) {
          // Avoid duplicate registrations:
          if (registeredServiceWorkerUrls.has(url)) continue

          // Register the URL:
          await navigator.serviceWorker.register(url)
          registeredServiceWorkerUrls.add(url)
        }

        // Retrieve the resulting `ServiceWorkerRegistration`:
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
        return resolve(registration)
      }
  )
}

let registeredSingletonServiceWorkerUrls = new Set()

function tick() {
  return new Promise(window.requestIdleCallback)
}
````

Answer (score 1):

you can use setTimeout

```
function registerServiceWorker() {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceWorker.js");
  }, 5 * 60 * 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceWorker.js");
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
    }, 300000);
}
```

The first parameter to `setTimeout()` is a callback that is called after the delay, and the second parameter is that delay in milliseconds (5 minutes = 300,000 milliseconds).

Also, as [Arman Charan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5566355/arman-charan) pointed out, if instead of waiting you want to immediately get the registration, then just await `navigator.serviceWorker.register`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceWorker.js");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael. If I wanted more control over when the service worker update occurs ie not at a set time, but at a time later when the app is not making any calls, would it be ok to not use the timer here - just flag if an update is available, which I then check via a timed function later which also checks that the app isn't making any calls? I guess I'd then have to make registration a global var (not a const) that I can access to inject into such a function (I tried a version of this using const but registration wasn't recognized elsewhere in my js). Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun That'd be fine, but I'd recommend using a callback rather than polling for a global variable to change. For example, make a function then call that function when you're ready.

Comment: MDN suggests that [`ServiceWorkerContainer.register()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register) [returns a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#return_value). Can it not just be `await`ed?

Comment: @ArmanCharan Good point, I've edited my answer for future visitors. However, in this case, I think OP really does want to wait 5 minutes (seems like a long time to keep running just to check right after it starts).

Comment: Yeah - the await is what I have, but it's problematic in that the prompt I show when a SW update is waiting gets replaced by other modal notifications I display while the app is getting it's CSRF token, setting up notifications etc. My solution was to wait until all other app init is done, then check if there's a SW update available. Initially I was doing the service worker check first, then getting my app token, but that got tricky as the SW checks would initially say that there's no update (triggering the rest of my app init), but then pick up that there's an update a few seconds later.